# How to prevent user copy and paste url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I developed course material in our website. I created the login page. Once after the user logged in you can find the link in the address bar.

If someone copies the link and pasted somewhere it should display as "404 error found".

Please some one help me how to do this?

Details:
wordpress

Comment: Do you want to prevent copying text from your HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

you can go with [WP Content Copy Protection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protection/) plugin .

Some of the most common content copy methods (via mouse, keyboard and browser), such as right-click, image drag/drop/save, text selection/drag/drop, source code viewing, and keyboard copy shortcut keys such as CTRL A, C, X, U, S, and P are disabled with this plugin (just to name a few).